# Is it correct to call pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() on the same condvar by different threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to understand how pthread_cond_broadcast() works and whether is possible to "attach" thread to the waiting list (or queue) of event (broadcast signal) that already blocked by another thread.

Let's assume that we have two threads.

Thread #1 in a waiting loop

```
pthread_mutex_lock();

while(condition_is_false) 

  pthread_cond_wait(); 

pthread_mutex_unlock();
```

And somewhere in the middle of this process when thread #1 already blocked then another thread #2 calls the same or almost the same code in hope to be "attached" to the same condvar:

```
pthread_mutex_lock();

while(condition_is_false) 

  pthread_cond_wait(); or pthread_cond_timedwait()

pthread_mutex_unlock();
```

As I understand thread #2 would not get access to the code locked by mutex until it will unlocked. Am I right?

I'm trying to implement next case: There are some tasks which required a time to be done. During that time another thread(s) not allowed to duplicate the same task that already in a progress but wait until it will finished. And when task will finally finished then all threads must get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is exactly the one for which condition variables are designed.

There is no problem for the second thread to achieve the lock on the mutex, because wait (and derivative) releases the mutex temporarily during wait and re-acquires it when coming back.

You should definitively read more in the abundant documentation about the concept of mutex and condition variables.

Comment: Thank you. The last question is about mixing pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() calls. Is it correct to use different functions on the same condvar?

Comment: @user3526517, sure, why wouldn't it?